# Boolean Difference failed - Give me an alternative

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I often model separate pieces and modify them with boolean operations to get to a final result.  I'm stuck with a quarter of a cone intersecting with a hollowed cube (think of an inverted tray). My goal is the union of the cone and the smaller portion of the cube/tray. In other words the cone is larger than the diagonal of the tray.  I'm not getting desired result in Blender 2.77, but I really think I'm missing a step somewhere.  If you don't have and answer for that, how about a link to  steps to manually do it? It really is simple, but I'm afraid I've been away too long.
Thanks for your thoughts.
[Looks like it worked - Nope](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rreru4jfsggfrb/qtr6.blend1?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your mesh is non-manifold, meaning you have holes on its surface, it can't boolean properly. To fix that, go in *Edit* mode, select the whole mesh, go in the *Mesh* menu > *Clean Up* > *Fill Holes*. Also you should recalculate the normals with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> even if it seems to work with bad normals. Then boolean with the *Union* mode and it works.

[image]

Comment: I used the "clean up" options in several different passes during the path to this point. Your observation is that one should use those tools just before doing a boolean modification.  Is there a required order?  Did "fill holes" take care of the problem or did you have to apply patches individually?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm off to see if I can replicate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what I've done is simply select your object, go in edit mode, Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes, then boolean, and it works, so if you tried the same thing and it didn't work I don't know the reason

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  I had earlier tried "Fill Holes" but apparently had other errors which kept the boolean from working.  Following your suggestion, I went to "Clean Up" and then every option on its menu and it worked.  I'm not suggesting it is a bug; I'm confessing that I'm not methodical in my work flow.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure but sometimes it looks like there are some bugs with booleans, but in your case it looks like when you fill the holes it works perfectly... your mesh is a bit messy though, but it's another problem  ;)